Webcam on Dell Latitude 7320 detachable (MIPI IPU6 tigerlake)
Plee
Hello folks!
I've had my Latitude 7320 for a few years now and everything works out of the box with Ubuntu, except for the webcam.  I've waited for years, and I'm now running 24.10 and still haven't been able to get this thing working. In this era it is very painful to have a webcam that does not work. There is at least one other person with my problem.
I've read a lot about this, and I believe that I have a MIPI ipu6 (tigerlake) architecture, which no longer uses USB so requires new packages. I see that there are many people out there running ubuntu with this type of webcam working, including official posts on the dell webpage.
Could someone please help a desperate soul here?
At the moment, I can't tell if there is a problem with loading the firmware, as it has an error message, but is followed by encouraging messages:
=> sudo dmesg | grep ipu
<snip>
[    2.857455] intel-ipu6 0000:00:05.0: Direct firmware load for intel/ipu6_fw.bin failed with error -2
[    2.864584] intel-ipu6 0000:00:05.0: FW version: 20230925
[    2.870327] intel-ipu6 0000:00:05.0: Found supported sensor OVTI8856:00
[    2.870334] intel-ipu6 0000:00:05.0: Connected 1 cameras

This may be due to the fact that the Oracular linux-firmware package installs a compressed version of this file at /lib/firmware/intel/ipu/ipu6se_fw.bin.zst. I did copy a version of ipu6_fw.bin to /lib/firmware/intel/ipu6se_fw.bin for good measure but continue to see the error.

What I've done
Diagnostics
The ipu6 video devices seem to show up
=> v4l2-ctl --list-devices
ipu6 (PCI:pci:pci0000:00):
    /dev/video1
    /dev/video2
    /dev/video3
    /dev/video4
    /dev/video5
    /dev/video6
    /dev/video7
    /dev/video8

ipu6 (pci:pci0000:00):
    /dev/media0

Intel MIPI Camera (platform:v4l2loopback-000):
    /dev/video0

but the driver info does not show IPU6
=> v4l2-ctl --all
Driver Info:
    Driver name      : v4l2 loopback
    Card type        : Intel MIPI Camera
    Bus info         : platform:v4l2loopback-000
    Driver version   : 6.11.0
    Capabilities     : 0x85200001
        Video Capture
        Read/Write
        Streaming
        Extended Pix Format
        Device Capabilities
    Device Caps      : 0x05200001
        Video Capture
        Read/Write
        Streaming
        Extended Pix Format

The driver seems to be loaded
=> sudo lshw -C multimedia
  *-multimedia:0            
       description: Multimedia controller
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 5
       bus info: pci@0000:00:05.0
       version: 01
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=intel-ipu6 latency=0
       resources: iomemory:600-5ff irq:169 memory:6052000000-6052ffffff

as well as the v4l2-relay daemon service.
The PPA package installation
Using this page as a guide, I added the OEM Solutions Group PPA for Intel MIPI IPU6. Here is what is listed on that PPA:

These don't appear to be installable packages:
=> sudo apt update
<snip>
Hit:7 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/oem-solutions-group/intel-ipu6/ubuntu oracular InRelease
All packages are up to date.    
=> sudo apt install ipu6-camera-bins
Error: Unable to locate package ipu6-camera-bins

but I can see the package details for each one of them. For example the gst-plugins-icamera package has this contents:

I can install the .deb packages listed each of them, with the exception of libipu6 which is a transitional package, so I don't believe it's a problem.

Firstly, the 'package' names you see are source packages not all the built binaries you can apt install.  You will need to know which produced binary packages are actually necessary for install. Additionally, not all the software is actually available for 24.10 in those repos.  Currently, the gstreamer1.0-icamera binaries are and you might want to start there, but if that doesn't work, you're going to have to research this on your own since that's a third party PPA from a group in Taipei. Note that the .tar.xz and .dsc are for building the packages, apt doesn't use them.

@ThomasWard thanks for the tip on the .tar.xz and .dsc files! I've installed all the binary .debs from those repos to no avail.

The bug says "Won't fix". It seems you have to write the driver yourself. Looks like Dell doesn't give a dam. I'm using ThinkPads for over 20 years with no problems on Linux

@kanehekili which bug are you referring to? The bug at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-firmware/+bug/1921345 is labeled as "fix released".

Okay so the .dsc (from what I can find online) is literally just a text file, probably documentation for the .tar.gz. Now that tar is going to be needed to be extracted, and possibly have to figure out how to install what ever it brings. Ubuntu and .debs aren't like .exe on Windows and they won't tell apt to do anything with the other files in the same folder. Also if you don't append "./" in front of the package name when using apt, then it won't look for the .deb in the local folder and instead only search the repositories.
Did you follow the instructions on the Dell web page you linked at the end of the second paragraph? Those instructions are for 22.04 and also for a different laptop. Not saying it's impossible those could work, but if it's the exact same webcam maybe it could. Also don't know how specific those drivers are to the version of Ubuntu. It's possible you might have to use the Ubuntu Restore Image for your specific laptop if that doesn't work. I imagine if you use Dells restore image you can the update it to the newest version after. Just don't know if it'll delete the driver in the update. Hopefully not.
Also not sure what app you're testing the camera in but from what I read in 2 different links already (of the ones you shared) that the preview doesn't work well in Cheese but that you can get it working by opening Cheese using the command "sudo cheese -d "Intel MIPI Camera"" in a terminal. You can probably create a shortcut or a script that opens it using that command. Not sure why it's run as sudo though. I would test to see if it works without sudo.

The .dsc is the definition of the source package for building it, defining changelog, etc. the Tarball is irrelevant to OP because they aren't building the packages themselves.  OP also said they installed all the binary .debs to no avail, which means the issue is beyond the PPA and the Tarball and OP will  have to find some other solution.  Refer to my comment on OP's post to understand that the .dsc and tarball are only relevant for building the packages not for using the built binaries.
